# extracting xml value in sproc

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, xquery

Assuming I have the following XML:

```
<root><test1>Hello</test1><test2>World</test2></root>
```

and in my stored procedure I have declared a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @Stuff nvarchar(50)
```

If the XML is passed into the stored procedure as

```
@MyXml
```

What would be the statement to parse the incoming XML to get the value held in element `test1`?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [xml type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) instead of nvarchar type, but the conversion is easy. Then you can query like this:

```
DECLARE @Stuff nvarchar(MAX) = '<root><test1>Hello</test1><test2>World</test2></root>'
DECLARE @Xml xml = @Stuff
SELECT @Xml.value('(/root/test1)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS Test1
```

For more information, see the [MSDN page on xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Comment: If the OP only wants to text inside the `<test1>` tag, there's really no need for the call to `.nodes()` - just use `SELECT @xml.value('(/root/test1)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')` and be done with it.

Comment: @marc_s - Good point. Answer updated. Out of curiosity, what do you gain by the '/text()'?

Comment: Nothing really - sometimes it seems to be needed to "tell" the SQL Server XQuery that you want to text contained in the XML tag - not necessary here, though